# editable and non-editable rows in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

How do I make some rows editable and some rows non-editable in slickgrid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the onBeforeEditCell event handler and return false to prevent the cell from going into edit mode.

Comment: Thanks Tin, adding the following code to the grid did the trick.
 grid.onBeforeEditCell = function(row, col, row) {
            if(row['key'] == "value") return false;
        };

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply designate some columns not to be editable without specifying any editor attribute.

Ex

```
columns = [
    {id:"id",name:"#",field:"id"},
    {id:"editable",name:"clicky",field:"editable",editor:Slick.Editors.Text}
];
```

Depends if you want to loop an auxiliary array and apply if criteria.

Hope it helps