# editable and noneditable cell in angular Slickgrid

Tags: angular, grid, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

firstly, want to clear that i want cell editable and noneditable not a row. I already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446763/editable-and-non-editable-rows-in-slickgrid). Take example of below image .Task0, Task2 should be editable but front row 65, 21 should not be editable and last row task4 and 1 both should be editable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other SO answer [editable and non-editable rows in slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446763/editable-and-non-editable-rows-in-slickgrid) that you are referring to is correct, the `onBeforeEditCell` is where you need to add your logic and then returning `true` will make the cell editable and returning `false` will be non-editable. I wrote this [Wiki - Disabling specific cell edit](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Editors#disabling-specific-cell-edit) which explains exactly that, I strongly suggest you to parse through all the available [Angular-Slickgrid - Wikis](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki) first